# Solving linear equation of complex matrices

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra, complex-numbers

I have a linear equation of a form ax=b where b is a complex matrix, and a is a real matrix. I'm expecting solution x to be a complex vector. When trying the `numpy.linalg.solve(a,b)` function, I'm getting this warning:

> ComplexWarning: Casting complex values to real discards the imaginary
> part

How do I solve this equation to preserve the complex numbers?

Comment: Cast the real matrix to complex?

Comment: How do I do it?

Comment: `np.linalg.solve` supports complex arrays, as the underlying LAPACK routines are ?gesv, which have a complex return type. I don't get warning you do whenever I try a combination of (complex, float) or (float, complex) arrays. I do get the error when I try to do `a.astype(float)`, but only the first time.

Comment: b.astype( complex )

Comment: Doesn't work in my case. The shape of a is 6x6, shape of b is 6x1, so I'm working with a matrix and a vector - does that change anything?

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Show us what values `a` and `b` have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split `b` into its real and imaginary components and solve the real/imaginary parts separately
Ax = b = A(xr+xi) = br + bi
A @ xr = br, A @ xi = bi

```py
br = np.real(b)
bi = np.imag(b)
A_inv = np.linalg.inv(A)
xr = A_inv @ br
xi = A_inv @ bi
x = xr + 1.j*xi
```

**EDIT**
The way you want to do it:

```py
x = np.linalg.solve(A, np.real(b)) + 1.j*np.linalg.solve(A, np.imag(b))
```

Comment: Thanks! It turned out both solutions worked fine when preceded with `x = np.zeros([6] ,dtype = "complex_" )`